# Proper/Secure encryption of data using AES and a password

Tags: encryption, passwords, aes, pbkdf2

Right now, this is what I am doing:
1. SHA-1 a password like "pass123", use the first 32 characters of the hexadecimal decoding for the key
2. Encrypt with AES-256 with just whatever the default parameters are
^Is that secure enough?

I need my application to encrypt data with a password, and securely. There are too many different things that come up when I google this and some things that I don't understand about it too. I am asking this as a general question, not any specific coding language (though I'm planning on using this with Java and with iOS).

So now that I am trying to do this more properly, please follow what I have in mind:

1. Input is a password such as "pass123" and the data is
   what I want to encrypt such as "The bank account is 038414838 and the pin is 5931"
2. Use PBKDF2 to derive a key from the password. Parameters:
   1000 iterations
   length of 256bits
   Salt - this one confuses me because I am not sure where to get the salt from, do I just make one up? As in, all my encryptions would always use the salt "F" for example (since apparently salts are 8bits which is just one character)
3. Now I take this key, and do I hash it?? Should I use something like SHA-256? Is that secure? And what is HMAC? Should I use that?
   Note: Do I need to perform both steps 2 and 3 or is just one or the other okay?
4. Okay now I have the 256-bit key to do the encryption with. So I perform the encryption using AES, but here's yet another confusing part (the parameters).
   I'm not really sure what are the different "modes" to use, apparently there's like CBC and EBC and a bunch of others
   I also am not sure about the "Initialization Vector," do I just make one up and always use that one?
   And then what about other options, what is PKCS7Padding?

Answer (score 1):

For your initial points:

1. Using hexadecimals clearly splits the key size in half. Basically, you are using AES-128 security wise. Not that that is bad, but you might also go for AES-128 and use 16 bytes.
2. SHA-1 is relatively safe for key derivation, but it shouldn't be used directly because of the existence/creation of rainbow tables. For this you need a function like PBKDF2 which uses an iteration count and salt.

As for the solution:

1. You should not encrypt PIN's if that can be avoided. Please make sure your passwords are safe enough, allow pass phrases.
2. Create a random number per password and save the salt (16 bytes) with the output of PBKDF2. The salt does not have to be secret, although you might want to include a system secret to add some extra security. The salt and password are hashed, so they may have any length to be compatible with PBKDF2.
3. No, you just save the secret generated by the PBKDF2, let the PBKDF2 generate more data when required.
4. Never use ECB (not EBC). Use CBC as minimum. Note that CBC encryption does *not* provide integrity checking (somebody might change the cipher text and you might never know it) or authenticity. For that, you might want to add an additional MAC, HMAC or use an encryption mode such as GCM. PKCS7Padding (identical to PKCS5Padding in most occurences) is a simple method of adding bogus data to get N * [blocksize] bytes, required by block wise encryption.

Don't forget to prepend a (random) IV to your cipher text in case you reuse your encryption keys. An IV is similar to a salt, but should be exactly [blocksize] bytes (16 for AES).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But I still have a few questions. First why not encrypt pins? Isn't this encryption (or at least the new suggested one) is good enough for encryptions? Secondly how could rainbow tables help here? The data is sent as ciphertext and if it gets intercepted no one has access to the sha-1 key (if they did they could crack it right then). Next does PBKDF2 use a hash as it goes along? Is that where I would use an HMAC calculated hash? And what would the secret key for the HMAC be? The same password or randomly generated? See more on the next comment (I'm running out of room)

Comment: Is the salt the same for all 1000 iterations using PBKDF2? If the salt is randomly generated how will the recipient know what the salt is (ideally all the recipient knows is the master password). If I prepend it to the ciphertext then what's the point of a salt. Lastly,  how would a random IV help (as opposed to 0)? Specifically how does it help in reusing encryption keys? If someone has discovered the key then they can decrypt any future cipher texts even if there is a random IV because they can read it directly off the cipher text. Thanks so much for your help

Comment: I'm sorry, but how many questions are go going to ask without doing any research yourself?

Comment: I've done research, and surprisingly there isn't one place that explains as it as it needs to be explained for this situation.